# Which Encounter cards are worth keeping after defeating them?

Tags: hand-of-fate

I always keep in my deck all the new encounter cards and encounters that will earn me a token. There's still some room left over in the encounter deck, though, which needs to be filled out with encounters I've already beaten at least once.

**Which encounters are good to keep around?**

Obviously, ones which are purely beneficial, such as the [Food Wagon](http://handoffate.gamepedia.com/Food_Wagon), are good. What I'm mainly interested in are ones that involve some risk, but have a good gain that more than makes up for it. One example I've had a lot of luck with so far would be [Deadman's Gorge](http://handoffate.gamepedia.com/Deadman's_Gorge). You fight one or two monster cards, and get three gain cards. That's a pretty good trade.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to fill the rest of my desk with encounter cards that have the most variety of rewards. Not sure if that is the best strategy though.

Example encounters:

[Dead King's Hall](http://handoffate.gamepedia.com/Dead_King%27s_Hall) - 3 gain cards, but you might get unlucky and also get a pain card.

[Goblins](http://handoffate.gamepedia.com/Goblins) - if you kill all the goblins, you will recover your equipment and gain some extra gold.

Comment: Holy crap an answer. I got a tumbleweed badge for this question. Variety is not a bad strategy in most games, gives you flexibility to deal with the current situation. To flesh out the answer: have any examples of which cards you're referring to?